# NSURLSessionConfiguration TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol looks like doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ssl, nsurlsession

From the beginning, how I configure `NSURLSession`:

```
auto securityPolicy = self.securityPolicy;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
config.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = [CSHTTPSessionWrapper minimumTLSprotocolForSecurityPolicy: securityPolicy]; // this properly sets values kTLSProtocol1, kTLSProtocol11, kTLSProtocol12

self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: config
                                             delegate: self
                                        delegateQueue: nil];
```

Nothing fancy.

Now I wrote some automated test which set security policy to TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and tries connect to `openssl` servers.
I wrote python script which starts this servers:

```
def run_ssl_server(name, openSSLBinary, port, params):
    print "Starting {0} server on port {1}".format(name, port)

    proc = subprocess.Popen([openSSLBinary, "s_server", "-cert", "testres/server.cert.pem", "-key", "testres/server.key.pem", "-debug", "-www", "-accept"] + [port] + params)
    atexit.register(proc.terminate)

    print "Server started. Pid={0}".format(proc.pid)

def main() :
    … … …
    openSSLBinary = arguments.openSSLBinary # use custom build of openssl

    server_modes = {
        'normal':         ('4433', []),
        'ssl3_only':      ('4435', ['-ssl3'])
    }

    openSSLVersion = open_ssl_tool_version(openSSLBinary)
    if openSSLVersion >= LooseVersion("1.0.0") :
        print "Adding servers which can be configured for openssl 1.0.0"
        server_modes.update({
            'no_tls2' : ('4434', ['-no_tls1_2']),
            'tls1'    : ('4436', ['-tls1']),
            'tls1_1'  : ('4437', ['-tls1_1']),
            'tls1_2'  : ('4438', ['-tls1_2']),
        })
    … … …
```

Since preinstalled `openssl` is quite old `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016` I've build new version and feed it to my python script.

Now test are checking all combinations of client minimum TLS version and server TLS version.
On Mac OS all tests are passing!

What is strange exactly same tests run on iOS emulator are failing when client have higher minimum TLS version than server supports. `NSURLSSession` returns success, no errors are reported (and they should)!

Exactly same test I did for sockets (`NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream`) and run on Mac and iOS emulator and they are passing, so problem is not a port forwarding on emulator.

It looks like that `NSURLSessionConfiguration` `TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol` doesn't work on iOS!

Does anyone has any advices, clues?
Or should I raise a bug report to Apple (I hate bug tracker Apple uses)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok issue is not reproducible on iOS 10, so apparently Apple already fix this bug (I've rerun test with Xcode 8.2.1).

Initially I did testing with iOS 9 (Xcode 7.2).