# TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol in URLSessionConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined the session configuration with the default configuration and provided the tlsMinimumSupportedProtocol as TLSv1.2 I am using Alamofire but my app is still supporting the lower version

[NSURLSessionConfiguration TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol looks like doesn't work on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834164/nsurlsessionconfiguration-tlsminimumsupportedprotocol-looks-like-doesnt-work-on)

`let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.tlsMinimumSupportedProtocol = .tlsProtocol12`

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```
tlsProtocol12
```

> Specifies that the TLS 1.2 protocol is preferred but lower versions
>   may be negotiated.

You need to change settings at the server side to allow only TLS 1.2

Comment: When I made it tlsProtocol11 it's still taking client support version as TLSv1.2

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Clean build and try.